# Problam with apt-get install

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and last week I try to install some virtual machine on my computer but I failed to do it.
Now when I try to install any program from the apt-get install I got this text:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git libssl-dev
[sudo] password for eliya: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.5).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavdevice-ffmpeg56 linux-headers-4.4.0-134 linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (5.1.38-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
removing old virtualbox extension packs
virtualbox-ext-pack: downloading: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.38/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
License accepted.
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: World writable: '/usr'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1201 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.38.vbox-extpack: expected e93d87b0f5de50369baca0a48082236b947df5b922ffd0233c0fa92c1206defd, or wrong accept-license key, removing the file.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And now i can't install anything because this problam.
Thank you

Comment: This is not a programming question, suggest you delete and ask on https://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 0):

1.Reconfigure Package Database

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

2.force install

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then try again installing virtualbox